# Waterproofing outdoor wire splices and receptacles

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, outdoor

It seems that the NEC requires wire splices to be UL486D listed when used in outdoor (generally damp or wet) locations, similar to the requirement for THWN or other wet-rated wiring.

Why are special wire nuts required when receptacles, like a duplex NEMA 5-20R, have exposed terminal screws? It seems that if the junction box were flooded, there would still be a short from the receptacle terminals.

Comment: Receptacles should never be installed where flooding is a significant possibility. Splices may occur elsewhere.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not saying they're installed where prone to flooding, but I think I see how that influences the requirements